# calculate sum, average array of object in js use reduce or for loop

Tags: javascript

I have array of object

```
 const users = [
     { group: 'editor', name: 'Adam', age: 23 },
     { group: 'editor', name: 'John', age: 28 },
     { group: 'editor', name: 'William', age: 34 },
     { group: 'admin', name: 'Oliver', age: 28' }
 ];
```

Expected result:

```
//sum
 sumAge = {
 editor: 85,  // 23+34+28
 admin: 28    // 28
}

//average
avgAge = {
   editor: 28.33,  // (85) / 3
   admin: 28    //(28)/1
}
```

I use `reduce()` method to group the objects in an array by 'group' and calculate sum:

```
let sumAge = users.reduce((group, age) => {
    group[age.group] = (group[age.group] || 0) + age.age || 1;
    return group;
}, {})
console.log('sumAge', sumAge); // sumAge: {editor: 85, admin: 28} 
done!
```

How to group object of Array by key 'group' and calculate average?.
I tried:

```
let ageAvg= users.reduce((group, age) => {
      if (!group[age.group]) {
      group[age.group] = { ...age, count: 1 }
         return group;
      }
      group[age.group].age+= age.age;
      group[age.group].count += 1;
      return group;
      }, {})
const result = Object.keys(ageAvg).map(function(x){
     const item  = ageAvg[x];
     return {
         group: item.group,
         ageAvg: item.age/item.count,
     }
 })
console.log('result',result);
/*
result=[
    {group: "editor", ageAvg: 28.33}
    {group: "admin", ageAvg: 28}
]
```

But Expected result:

```
result = {
   editor: 28.33,  // (85) / 3
   admin: 28    //(28)/1
}
```

Comment: If you want a single object, `map()` will not work for you.  And if you want just `group: average`, then your return inside that map doesn't match that at all

Comment: Otherwise, `reduce()` the result of that map to the single object you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `reduce` to combine age values per group, then `map` to compute averages per key and convert back to an object with `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const users = [
  { group: 'editor', name: 'Adam', age: 23 },
  { group: 'editor', name: 'John', age: 28 },
  { group: 'editor', name: 'William', age: 34 },
  { group: 'admin', name: 'Oliver', age: 28 }
];

const grouped = users.reduce((a, e) => {
  if (!a[e.group]) {
    a[e.group] = [];
  }
  
  a[e.group].push(e.age);
  return a;
}, {});

const avgs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(grouped).map(([k, v]) => [
    k, v.reduce((a, e) => a + e, 0) / v.length
  ])
);

console.log(avgs);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying to my post... I don't understand code : const avgs = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(grouped).map(([k, v]) => [
    k, v.reduce((a, e) => a + e, 0) / v.length
  ])
);

Comment: What about it don't you understand? `Object.entries` dumps an object into an array of pairs, `map`'s callback takes the average of each array and `Object.fromEntries` converts the entry pairs back into an object. Please see the docs for each function, and/or split it into multiple intermediate variables and print each one as you go.

Comment: @ggorlen - you point out this is a duplicate of minhminh's previous post; how about putting this answer _there_ and help to close this dupe?

Comment: @StephenP I didn't realize it was a dupe until after I'd posted my answer. I'll vote to delete whichever post gets closed first.

Comment: @ggorlen. OP is posting this question multiple times - in this question i answered exactly that was mentioned in the expected output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374505/how-to-group-by-calculate-sum-and-get-average-in-javascript-array/63374937#63374937).